# Does "mov ax, 5" put data on CPU's memory/cache or the main RAM?

Tags: assembly, cpu, intel

When issuing `mov ax, 5`, where does the data actually end up in? Does it go to the CPU's own memory/cache or to the RAM? Or does it fill the CPUs as long as it's not full, and the rest will go to the RAM? In that case do each application receive their own slice in the CPU's memory/cache or how does it work?

I realize this can be very CPU dependent. I'm mainly interested in Windows + Intel modern CPUs like Core series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AX` is a register. This is all done inside registers, or "CPU memory" if that's what you'd like to call it.

Comment: What happens when it becomes full? How would you write into RAM, instead?

Comment: @rFactor: Not sure what you mean -- it *overwrites* `AX`, just like a variable. Nothing becomes full...

Comment: Registers don't get full. There are a finite number of them. When you load a new value into a register, the previous value of that register is simply overwritten.

Comment: @Mehrdad: how would I write into the RAM?

Comment: @rFactor: You need a memory address. Where do you want to write?

Comment: `MOV [address], 5` for a literal, or to copy from register to memory, `MOV [address], AX`

Comment: @David: Ah that was exactly what I was looking for, I've forgotten that entirely, have not really done much in Intel x86 asm.